# AWS query through Qt (mac - OSX) is not getting any result

Tags: c++, macos, qt, amazon-web-services

I'm currently trying to create a C++ program to track prices for a bunch of ASINs.
I'm using C++ with Qt (Version 5.5), compiling on mac OSX through Xcode (5.1.1).
When compiling, it's running but no output is given. I have the following warning message instead (I encrypted AccessKey & AssociateTag for privacy reasons as "/////////////")

```
*QUrl("http://ecs.amazonaws.com/onca/xml?AWSAccessKeyId=///////////////&AssociateTag=/////////////&ItemId=B00181T20O&Operation=ItemLookup&ResponseGroup=OfferSummary&Service=AWSECommerceService&Signature=1K69SLmTkZ9hZwwt5ualR4uDRwY%3D&SignatureMethod=HmacSHA1&Timestamp=2017-01-04T10%3A21%3A46Z")
qt.network.ssl: Error receiving trust for a CA certificate
qt.network.ssl: Error receiving trust for a CA certificate
qt.network.ssl: Error receiving trust for a CA certificate
qt.network.ssl: Error receiving trust for a CA certificate
qt.network.ssl: Error receiving trust for a CA certificate
qt.network.ssl: Error receiving trust for a CA certificate
qt.network.ssl: Error receiving trust for a CA certificate
qt.network.ssl: Error receiving trust for a CA certificate
qt.network.ssl: Error receiving trust for a CA certificate
qt.network.ssl: Error receiving trust for a CA certificate
"<?xml version=\"1.0\"?>\n<ItemLookupErrorResponse 
xmlns=\"http://ecs.amazonaws.com/doc/2005-10-05/\"><Error>
<Code>SignatureDoesNotMatch</Code><Message>The request signature we calculated 
does not match the signature you provided. Check your AWS Secret Access Key and 
signing method. Consult the service documentation for details.</Message></Error>
<RequestId>f4626242-a110-43f1-9b56-b8a696b3f299</RequestId>
</ItemLookupErrorResponse>"

RET:
("", "")*
```

To test it again, I copied URL (first few rows of warning message) in the browser and I get the same error as well:
*"The request signature we calculated does not match the signature you provided. Check your AWS Secret Access Key and signing method. Consult the service documentation for details."*

Can anyone give me a hint of what's wrong in the URL? 
Thanks in advance!

Comment: Could you provide us a basic code example?

Comment: I try to enter the part that seems most relevant to me (I can't embed the whole .zip file)

Comment: error should be on the SignatureMethod, according to my A|B testing, but cannot find which method to use.

Answer (score 0):

this is the most relevant part of the code. I suspect I cannot embed .zip file

```
AWSQueryRequest::AWSQueryRequest(QObject *parent) :
    QObject(parent)
{
    m_netManager = new QNetworkAccessManager(this);
}

QString AWSQueryRequest::hmacSha1(QByteArray key, QByteArray baseString)
{
    int blockSize = 64; // HMAC-SHA-1 block size, defined in SHA-1 standard
    if (key.length() > blockSize)
    {
        // if key is longer than block size (64), reduce key length with SHA-1 compression
        key = QCryptographicHash::hash(key, QCryptographicHash::Sha1);
    }

    QByteArray innerPadding(blockSize, char(0x36)); // initialize inner padding with char "6"
    QByteArray outerPadding(blockSize, char(0x5c)); // initialize outer padding with char "quot;
    // ascii characters 0x36 ("6") and 0x5c ("quot;) are selected because they have large
    // Hamming distance (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hamming_distance)

    for (int i = 0; i < key.length(); i++)
    {
        innerPadding[i] = innerPadding[i] ^ key.at(i); // XOR operation between every byte in key and innerpadding, of key length
        outerPadding[i] = outerPadding[i] ^ key.at(i); // XOR operation between every byte in key and outerpadding, of key length
    }

    // result = hash ( outerPadding CONCAT hash ( innerPadding CONCAT baseString ) ).toBase64
    QByteArray total = outerPadding;
    QByteArray part = innerPadding;
    part.append(baseString);
    total.append(QCryptographicHash::hash(part, QCryptographicHash::Sha1));
    QByteArray hashed = QCryptographicHash::hash(total, QCryptographicHash::Sha1);
    return hashed.toBase64();
}

QByteArray AWSQueryRequest::getTimeStamp()
{
    QDateTime dateTime = QDateTime::currentDateTimeUtc();
    return dateTime.toString(Qt::ISODate).toUtf8();
}

QByteArray AWSQueryRequest::createSignature(const QMap<QString,QString> & queryItems)
{
    QUrl url(END_POINT);
    QString stringToSign = "GET\n";
    stringToSign.append(url.host() + "\n");
    stringToSign.append(url.path() + "\n");

    QList<QString> keys = queryItems.keys();
    for( int i=0; i < keys.count() ; ++i )
    {
        stringToSign.append(keys[i]+"="+queryItems[keys[i]]);
        if( i != keys.count() -1  )
            stringToSign.append("&");
    }
    QString signature = hmacSha1(AWS_PASS, stringToSign.toUtf8());
    return QUrl::toPercentEncoding(signature);
}
#if 0
QByteArray AWSQueryRequest::createSignature(const QList< QPair<QString,QString> > & queryItems)
{
    QUrl url(END_POINT);
    QString stringToSign = "GET\n";
    stringToSign.append(url.host() + "\n");
    stringToSign.append(url.path() + "\n");

    for (int i=0; i<queryItems.count(); ++i)
    {
        QPair<QString,QString> pairValue = queryItems[i];
        stringToSign.append(pairValue.first+"="+pairValue.second);
        if( i != queryItems.count() -1)
            stringToSign.append("&");
    }

    QString signature = hmacSha1(AWS_PASS, stringToSign.toUtf8());
    return QUrl::toPercentEncoding(signature);
}
#endif
QUrl AWSQueryRequest::createUrl( const QMap< QString,QString >& queryItems )
{
    QUrl url(END_POINT);
    QUrlQuery query;
    QMapIterator<QString, QString> it(queryItems);
    while (it.hasNext())
    {
        it.next();
        query.addQueryItem(it.key().toUtf8(), it.value().toUtf8());
    }
    url.setQuery(query);
    return url;

}
```